# Запретить конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания

Tags: c++, конструктор

Если в базовом классе запретить конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания, нужно ли в производных классах делать то же самое?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это делать не обязательно. Например есть вспомогательный класс [`boost::non_copyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html) который используется чтобы запретить копирование.

Однако, при попытке копирования в сообщении об ошибке будет написано только про `boost::non_copyable`, но не про класс-наследник, что затруднит понимание в каком именно месте произошла ошибка.

Поэтому лучше запрещать копирование явно, в классе-наследнике. Рекомендуемый способ - это `=delete;`

```
struct X {
  X(const X&) = delete;
  X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
};
```

Если код компилируется для С++03, то конструктор и оператор присваивания надо объявить в `private` секции, и не определять. Тогда будет либо ошибка компиляции (из за private), либо ошибка линковки.

```
struct X {
private:
  X(const X&);  // noncopyable
  X& operator=(const X&);  // noncopyable
};
```

Comment: `= delete` появился в 11 стандарте. Если версия используемого компилятором стандарта более раняя (точнее, не используемая, а "та, которой он придерживается"), то нужно объявить оператор, но ничего не писать в теле.

`X(Xconst&);`